# I am trying to replace 0s in a data set by randomly -1 or +1, but it does not work, is there a function I have not considered?

Tags: r

This is my current code:

```
df.no_missings$prv.arm <- replace(df.no_missings$prv.arm, df.no_missings$prv.arm == 0,sample(c(-1,1), size =30, replace = TRUE))
```

It works, but each time I run the script again I get another output. I want it to be set once though and now tried:

```
df.no_missings$prv.arm <- set.seed(replace(df.no_missings$prv.arm, df.no_missings$prv.arm == 0,sample(c(-1,1), size =30, replace = TRUE)))
```

but then the 0s are not replaced but simply ignored once I ask for the new number of -1 and +1s in the data set.

Anyone knows how I can solve this, so all 61 zero values will randomly be replaced by either -1 or +1 and then stay in that new replacement distribution every time I run the skript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the seed of R‘s random number generator, which is useful for creating simulations or random objects that can be reproduced.

```
set.seed(42)
df.no_missings$prv.arm <- replace(df.no_missings$prv.arm, df.no_missings$prv.arm == 0,sample(c(-1,1), size =30, replace = TRUE))
```

Change 42 with any number you like